# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'inventory_on_hand'

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-mapping

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        products0_.id as id1_1_,
        products0_.inventory_on_hand as inventor2_1_,
        products0_.inventory_received as inventor3_1_,
        products0_.inventory_shipped as inventor4_1_,
        products0_.minimum_required as minimum_5_1_,
        products0_.part_number as part_num6_1_,
        products0_.product_label as product_7_1_,
        products0_.product_name as product_8_1_,
        products0_.starting_inventory as starting9_1_ 
    from
        products products0_
2020-02-07 16:41:43.914  WARN 15224 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 207, SQLState: S0001
2020-02-07 16:41:43.914 ERROR 15224 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Invalid column name 'inventory_on_hand'.
2020-02-07 16:41:43.926 ERROR 15224 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'inventory_on_hand'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1624) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:594) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:524) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2979) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:248) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
```

Any suggestion

Comment: `products0_ should` have a column named `inventory_on_hand` name mismatch is there

Comment: Whats table structure looks like?

Comment: table structure is     CREATE TABLE [dbo].[products](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [ProductName] [varchar](255) NULL,
 [PartNumber] [varchar](255) NULL,
 [ProductLabel] [varchar](255) NULL,
 [StartingInventory] [int] NULL,
 [InventoryReceived] [int] NULL,
 [InventoryShipped] [int] NULL,
 [InventoryOnHand] [int] NULL,
 [MinimumRequired] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
)